# google_mobile_ads 0.13.0 plugin banner ads are auto reload when setstate call in flutter app

Tags: flutter, admob, ads, banner

I try to use setstate function to update ui but automatic admob ads are reloaded and when use with audio player then ads are blinking or rebuild very fast admob banner ads widget.
any have idea how to solve this problem in flutter
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

```
class BannerAdUnit1 extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_BannerAdUnit1State createState() => _BannerAdUnit1State();
}

class _BannerAdUnit1State extends State<BannerAdUnit1> {
static BannerAd myBanner;
bool showAds = false;
@override
void initState() {
    bannerAd();
    super.initState();
    myBanner.load();
    myBanner..responseInfo;
  }

BannerAd bannerAd() {
 myBanner = new BannerAd(
    adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
    size: AdSize.smartBanner,
    request: AdRequest(),
    listener: BannerAdListener(
      onAdLoaded: (ad) {
      print('admob is loaded or loading');
        setState(() {
          showAds = true;
        });
      },
      onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
      print('admob is dispose or disposing');
        ad.dispose();
        setState(() {
          showAds = false;
        });
      },
    ),
  );
  return myBanner;
 }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    myBanner.dispose();
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('printing ads widget fxn.....................');
    return showAds
        ? Container(
            height: 52,
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, top: 5,
         left: 8, right: 8),
            child: AdWidget(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              ad: myBanner,
            ),
          )
        : Container();
 }
}
```

this use code of banner as widget

Answer (score 1):

try making putting the showAd = false in initstate

try this:

```
  `class BannerAdUnit1 extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_BannerAdUnit1State createState() => _BannerAdUnit1State();
}

class _BannerAdUnit1State extends State<BannerAdUnit1> {
static BannerAd myBanner;
bool showAds = false;
@override
void initState() {
bannerAd();
super.initState();
myBanner.load();
myBanner..responseInfo;
bool showAds = false;
}

BannerAd bannerAd() {
myBanner = new BannerAd(
adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
size: AdSize.smartBanner,
request: AdRequest(),
listener: BannerAdListener(
  onAdLoaded: (ad) {
  print('admob is loaded or loading');
    setState(() {
      showAds = true;
    });
  },
  onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
  print('admob is dispose or disposing');
    ad.dispose();
    setState(() {
      showAds = false;
    });
  },
),
);
 return myBanner;
   }

  @override
  void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  myBanner.dispose();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print('printing ads widget fxn.....................');
  return showAds
    ? Container(
        height: 52,
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, top: 5,
     left: 8, right: 8),
        child: AdWidget(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          ad: myBanner,
        ),
      )
    : Container();
  }
   }  `
```

Comment: i already dispose ads but still reload ad